# Locked out of drupal

Tags: users

I managed to lock myself out of drupal by removing the user login block.  Is there any file I can modify to enable myself to get back in?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try: `www.example.com/?q=user`.

Comment: Indeed, if that doesn't work then your site is in really bad shape!